# Unable to get the user name and role of the user accessing the website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the name and role of the user who is currently accessing the web application but the code I have written fetches the server user name.

Could you please review the below code that I have written and tell a solution to this problem.

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\\" };
string[] uname = userName.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
userName = uname[1];
List<string> userRoles = new List<string>();
userRoles = getUserRole(userName);

public List<string> getUserRole(string userName)
{
    List<string> userNestedMembership = new List<string>();  

    DirectoryEntry domainConnection = new DirectoryEntry(); // Use this to query the default domain

    DirectorySearcher samSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();  

    samSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;  
    samSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=" + userName + ")";  
    samSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");  

    SearchResult samResult = samSearcher.FindOne();

    if (samResult != null)
    {
        DirectoryEntry theUser = samResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
        theUser.RefreshCache(new string[] { "tokenGroups" });

        foreach (byte[] resultBytes in theUser.Properties["tokenGroups"])
        {
            System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier mySID = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(resultBytes, 0);

            DirectorySearcher sidSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();

            sidSearcher.SearchRoot = domainConnection;
            sidSearcher.Filter = "(objectSid=" + mySID.Value + ")";
            sidSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

            SearchResult sidResult = sidSearcher.FindOne();

            if (sidResult != null)
            {
                string role = (string)sidResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0];
                role = role.Substring(3, role.Length - 3);
                string[] roles = role.Split(',');
                userNestedMembership.Add(roles[0]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have not done any changes in web config.

Comment: How is the user authenticating with the website?

Comment: It is an internal website which will be used by users of a specific department. I am trying to get the user name, display name and user role of the person who is accessing the website. I have tried multiple things but everytime its giving me the name of the app pool user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

That is getting you the wndows user name, which is likely the apppool name.

Have you set thr web config and IIS to know thet you want to use windows auth?

(or if you are not, try using the HTTP Context

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Hope this helps, or at least gives you a steer in the right direction

Comment: I tried it but still its giving me the app pool identity.

Comment: What does your web config (the authentication section) look like?

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably doesn't lie in the code, but in environment configuration. There are specific requirements to be met, to make `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` work as you want, as it gets the user on the server side. [Here is nice post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1928330.aspx?System%20Security%20Principal%20is%20giving%20Netwrok%20Service%20) describing what could be done to make IIS work under user account (with Windows Authentication).

Comment: I tried it but still its giving me the app pool identity.